# Loopback cannot update User/Customer using PUT request

Tags: authorization, loopbackjs, put

I have a Customer model which extends the builtin User Model. But the PUT request to Update customer does not work at all, even after providing correct access_token.

I logged in as a user using the login endpoint and got the access_token.
The PUT request to update the customer attributes:

```
PUT  http://localhost:3000/api/customers/59cb873ab21a902ab0afece1
```

As per my understanding the owner should be able to update his own record, But it keeps throwing the following error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "statusCode": 401,
        "name": "Error",
        "message": "Authorization Required"
    }
}
```

Also, when I try to delete using the same access_token it works fine.

```
DELETE  http://localhost:3000/api/customers/59cb873ab21a902ab0afece1
```

The customer.json file looks like below:

```
{
  "name": "customer",
  "plural": "customers",
  "base": "User",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "realm": null,
    "emailVerified": null,
    "name": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "username": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "cellnumber": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "status": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "accessTokens": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "accessToken",
      "foreignKey": "userId"
    }
  },
  "acls": [
  ],
  "methods": {},
  "replaceOnPUT": false
}
```

Where am I going wrong ? How do I fix this issue ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try providing USER, ACL like following example,

```
"acls": [
    {
      "accessType": "EXECUTE",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$authenticated",
      "permission": "ALLOW"
    }, {
      "accessType": "*",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$everyone",
      "permission": "DENY"
    }
  ]
```

hope this will work.

Comment: No, it doesn't work. What is the use of adding more ACL's when the default User model already has one. The problem is that the default ACL does not work.

Answer (score 0):

The default ACL for User model requires authentification, on every requests excepted the POST request - so it's not an issue.

To make GET, PUT/PATCH or DELETE requests on this model you need to login and use a token in your requests.

Example in your case:

- POST a new Customer like: 
  `{
  "username": "stack_user",
  "email": "test@stackoverflow.com",
  "password":"stackoverflow"
  }`;
  at `POST  http://localhost:3000/api/customers/`
- LOGIN using email and password : `{
  "email": "test@stackoverflow.com",
  "password":"stackoverflow"
  }`;
  at `POST  http://localhost:3000/api/customers/login`

=> you will get a response like :

```
{
  "id": "jazSRZYbjJai3JeCYpb6u4nYsRGWbaQk5SK3nQPkMoNeUdrAYK3kYwaXECrfj6Vk",
  "ttl": 1209600,
  "created": "2017-09-29T11:44:16.111Z",
  "userId": "59cb873ab21a902ab0afece1"
}
```

where **id** is the access_token.

- Use it at `PUT  http://localhost:3000/api/customers/59cb873ab21a902ab0afece1?access_token=jazSRZYbjJai3JeCYpb6u4nYsRGWbaQk5SK3nQPkMoNeUdrAYK3kYwaXECrfj6Vk`

and it should work.

---

If not, can you try to remove this line:

```
"replaceOnPUT": false
```

and try again?

Comment: Hi F3LIX79, I am following the same, but it does not work. Removing replaceOnPut does not help either. It seems to be a problem when we extend the default User model.

Comment: Do you manage to make it working in the Swagger 'API Explorer' by setting the access token in right above corner of your browser page?

Comment: Nope.. it does not work using access token either in the API swagger or  Postman.

Comment: Well it's strange. You might want to update your components.